# Regular expression: how to deal with character /

Tags: regex, linux, debian, grafana, zabbix

I’m using grafana to get zabbix agent data.

I need to match only one of these following values:

> Free space on C: (Percentage)
>
> Free Space on / (Percentage)

This expression doesn’t let match the second one:

```
/^(Free space on C: (Percentage)|Free Space on \/ (Percentage))$/
```

Even in online regex text doesn’t match as well.

I’m pretty sure the problem is with the character /.

Comment: Shouldn't match any of them. You'll have to escape the parentheses. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/554v7v/1)

Answer (score 0):

What about if you escape the forward slash with a forward slash, like this?

```
/^(Free space on C: (Percentage)|Free Space on // (Percentage))$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nWNDgO/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^Free [Ss]pace on (?:C:|\/) \(Percentage\)$/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nWNDgO/1)

Answer (score 0):

To match one of your values you have to escape `\` the parenthesis around `(Percentage)`

[`^(Free space on C: \(Percentage\)|Free Space on \/ \(Percentage\))$`](https://regex101.com/r/BN0mG4/1/)

If you only want to match your values might use a non capturing group `^(?:`